# Layout constraints changing after scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

So i have a tableview with N amount of rows. The tableview is designed like a swimming track. Each row has a swimmer image and the swimmer's X location is based upon their position in the race.

The UITableViewCell has been designed with IB and using Autolayout Constraints.

Each cell swimmer gets their position from an index of an array, ie...

**// Method - cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

cell.swimmerLeading.constant = [_array[indexPath.row] integerValue]

Whenever i scroll, the swimmerLeading.constant gets reset back to its original value of 8;

Any clues as to why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
[self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RacePredictorTrackTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TrackCell"];
...

}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == TableSectionTrack) {

        RacePredictorTrackTableViewCell *cell = (RacePredictorTrackTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TrackCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.indexPath = indexPath;

        Runner *runner = _runners[indexPath.row];

        cell.isStarred = NO;
        cell.cellPositionlabel.text = runner.predictorPlace;
        cell.cellPercentageFloat = runner.predictorRanking.floatValue;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

cell.cellPercentageFloat is just a setter method that sets the value to two constraints, swimmer and label for swimmer

**RacePredictorTrackTableViewCell.m**

```
- (void)setCellPercentageFloat:(CGFloat)cellPercentageFloat {
    cellPercentageFloat = cellPercentageFloat / 100;
    CGFloat labelWidth = _cellHorseLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width;
    CGFloat labelRaceLineBuffer = 8;
    _horseImageViewLeading.constant = (self.totalSpace * cellPercentageFloat) + kOriginalHorseImageViewLeading;;

    if ((_horseImageViewLeading.constant + _horseImageViewWidth.constant) > labelWidth) {
        _horseLabelLeading.constant = (_horseImageViewLeading.constant + _horseImageViewWidth.constant) - labelWidth - labelRaceLineBuffer;
    } else {
        _horseLabelLeading.constant = _horseImageViewLeading.constant;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post your entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method. What you're describing definitely shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Ok, I don't see any constraint code there. If that's in the cellPercentageFloat method, then you need to post that too.

Comment: One thing that seems to be missing is actually setting the value of cellPercentageFloat in your setter -- you should have a line like, _cellPercentageFloat = cellPercentageFloat; (assuming that your property is named cellPercentageFloat, and it has the default backing ivar of _cellPercentageFloat). Are the positions of the views correct when the table first loads, and then they all move to 8 when you scroll?